# Kubectl command to figure out Linux distro and version

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a `Kubectl` command to figure out the following info about a `Pod`?

1. The installed Linux distribution
2. The OS version

Let's say you don't really have a good deal of info about the image with which a `Deployment` or a `Pod` has been created...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something as simple as this using exec will result the os details

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx1 -- /bin/bash -c "cat /etc/os-release;uname -r"
```

Should result this

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
4.4.0-169-generic
```

Comment: This will give you the os-release of the container, but not the host operating system.